# Ruby/Rails: wkhtmltopdf Hanging Only if Waiting for PDF Write to Finish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf

Ruby Version: 2.5.7

Rails Version: 4.2.11

wkhtmltopdf version: wkhtmltopdf-binary gem (0.12.6.5)

Method to write to server: Open4::popen4

wkhtmltopdf is working very well, as long as I don't use a loop, sleep, or Process.waitpid2 to determine when the file write is complete. Using those methods for polling causes Puma to hang. This leaves me in the tough position of not knowing when the file is successfully written.

Hanging Ruby Code (in a Resque Job):

```rb
cmd = "wkhtmltopdf -q #{params} #{opts['url']} #{server_filepath(uuid)}"

pid, stdin, stdout, stderr = Open4::popen4(cmd)

Process.waitpid2(pid)

completed('url_path' => "/profile/#{uuid}/get_profile_pdf")
```

If you remove the `Process.waitpid2(pid)` call it works but the user is redirected before the file is written.

I've attempted what seems like everything, including calling `Open4::popen4` as a block to evaluate `stdout` like so:

```rb
Open4::popen4(cmd) do |pid, stdin, stdout, stderr|
  # Using this causes the thread to hang as well.
end
```

Lastly I moved my code to the client, polling via Javascript, but it dawned on me that in a clustered environment this is a bad idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.